Wrong shadows in render mode
I am new to blender and this is my first post. 
I started modeling a robot head and the "eyebrows" have a wrong shadows. As you can see in the shadows there is a distance between the eyebrows and the box-head, allthough the eyebrows have no distance to the head. Render Engine is Eevee in the above screenshot. I just switched it to cycles and now the box-head appears black, allthough the material is white.
I appreaciate any help!
Thanks in advance,
lf11


This question is similar to: Eevee displays shadows as though they levitate, Shadows of small objects in Eevee, Why is world light bleeding in EEVEE?, Eevee contact shadows VS model complexity

The shadows and the black box in Cycles are two separate questions, on this it is preferred to ask one issue per post... on my PC the head is not black. Maybe you need to update your GPU drivers?

Thanks Gordon, your first link solved the problem with the shadows. I needed to activate  "contact shadows" on the light. I will add another question for the black box with cycles. Best regards, lf11

I just saw there can also be problems with the head from Z-fighting because of overlapping faces: you are using a Mirror modifier on the head (probably to duplicate the eye), but the cuboid for the head has its geometry to both sides of the mirror axis, so you mirror the left side to the right and vice versa. You have to split the cuboid in the center with a loop cut and then delete one half (preferably you keep the half where the eye is to model everything on one side).

Thanks Gordon! I did as you suggested and it was the z-fighting!! I thought the mirror modifier would "delete" the other half. I am very grateful!

When you use the AutoMirror tool with the (by default enabled) option Cut and Mirror, then the object will be cut along the chosen axis, one half automatically be deleted and a Mirror modifier added. When you just manually add a Mirror modifier, nothing of this will happen automatically.

Great advice, just what i need to built the robot as i wanted. Greetings from Luebeck, Germany! :-)
